# Attraction of a Bullet due to Gravity in a Perfect Vaccum

Tags: classical-mechanics, vacuum

*I realise that this might be conventially very difficult to answer because there's no KG or Newtons in space, only particles.*

As far as I understand, every object creates a 'pull' due to the forces of gravity, that'll be felt noticeably by smaller objects (as well as the larger object being attracted 'less' to it). If we fire a bullet in a straight line on earth it'll curve down towards the earth and hit it because of the force of gravity.

If we say had a bullet fired in a straight line in space, and an object 1km away at say 30 degrees from the main path, is there any way we can work out how massive that object would have to be for the bullet to hit it.

Say the bullet is fired at 10m/s and is on Earth 20g - it's not really the figures I'd just wonder if it's possible.

Comment: No Newtons in space? Care to clarify?

Comment: Sorry should've made that clearer. What I mean is on Earth we can say 70kg, or due to the Fact W=mg 687N. If there's no outside gravity, then saying it's whatever Newtons on Earth doesn't really mean everything because Mass x 0 will always be 0N, so I guess you'd have to have to use another scales if it's possible, but I really don't know, and I might be totally wrong in what I've just said.

Comment: There is gravity in space. And EVERY object has mass or "KG", independet if they're on a planet or in absolute vacuum (given that it doesn't vaporize).

Comment: Both mass and force are relevant "in space". Even "weight = mass time gravitational acceleration" is relevant, though "gravitational acceleration" is not the same and may not be constant in the problem.

Comment: 1) If I understand you correctly then you are saying that objects in space have no *weight*. However they do have mass and gravity works on mass. 2) If I got that right then the situation in your question is this:  (Picture with a 1km long distance (black line), 30 degrees (marked in green), thus known distance 'blue')? http://i.stack.imgur.com/L2lLU.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the scale involved, the object would have to be much more massive than the bullet, so the answer will be independent of the mass of the bullet, just as objects of different mass undergo the same acceleration due to gravity. (Phrased differently, we can ask what the reduced mass needs to be).

To answer the question, you would have to specify how big the object is also. If all the mass is concentrated into a point, then black holes aside, the bullet can't hit it and conserve angular momentum at the same time. A good treatment of the problem involves solving Kepler's law, but more details are need.

You can get an *order-of-magnitude* answer by finding out what transverse acceleration is needed to deflect the bullet by $0.5\,km$ in $t$ seconds, i.e., $g \approx \frac{1000m}{t^2}$ and $t$ solves $1000m = (10 \frac{m}{s}) t + \frac{1}{2} g t^2$. Then
$500m = (10 \frac{m}{s})t$, so $t =50s$ so $g \approx 0.4 \frac{m}{s^2}$. Here I am treating the $x$ and $y$ coordinates as both subject to the same acceleration of constant magnitude $g$, which is *not at all orbital motion* and only meant to give a ballpark figure. Hopefully nobody decides to crucify me.

Ok so the bullet is undergoing $g \approx 0.4 \frac{m}{s^2}$ at a distance $r \approx 1118m$. Into $g = \frac{G M}{r^2}$ we get $M \approx \frac{g r^2}{G}$ works out to be roughly $M \approx 7\times 10^{15} kg$.

The [largest asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_notable_asteroids) have masses well in excess of $10^{18} kg$.